# Is command injection possible within shell scripts without the use of eval?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, security, code-injection

I was wondering, nowadays with the most recent versions of sh, bash, ksh etc. is it possible to get command injection by executing this (very simple) script?

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "What is the name of the program you are looking for?"
read program
locate $program
```

Despite of the fact that one can already execute code if they have a shell of course, I am just wondering if a variable can contain malicious code like for example in PHP:

```
parameter=parameter;ls
```

Also shellshock (env variables) can be ignored in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But it is not so simple as you mention.
See below some example.

It will not works:

```
$ read -p "Type some text:" var1
Type some text:Example;hostname

$ echo $var1
Example;hostname

$ $var1
Example;hostname: command not found
```

But if you use like this, yes, it will work:

```
$ read -p "Type some text:" var1
Type some text:hostname

$ echo $var1
hostname

$ $var1
SSBLZMVM1
```

Answer (score 1):

If written like that, you never know if there isn't a shell implementation out there which could be tricked like that. You can be on the safe side however by putting the argument of locate in quotation marks. Then the expanded parameter will be treated as a *single* word:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "What is the name of the program you are looking for?"
read program
locate "${program}"
```

Comment: Thank you, however why should I do that, besides best practices, if command injection is not possible at all in the first place? If it is however possilble, please show me a working example on how to.

Comment: Are you looking for a way of command injection or are you trying to make your scripts more secure? You never know how old implementations would behave, that's why it's good to follow best practices.

Comment: as stated in the question: nowadays with the most recent versions of sh, bash, ksh etc. just to know if it is doable to manipulate the command being executed and if there is a way to get command injection.
I know for example it is safer to do prepared statements in sql, even if sqli gets filtered through a web framework. I was just wondering if command injection through shell scripts still existed in 2015 when programming like this.